# dotnet maui blazor app crashes on iphone device just by adding builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectivity>(Connectivity.Current) to MauiProgram.cs

Tags: .net, blazor, native, maui, xamarin.essentials

Build Setup:
Macbook Air(M1, 2020)
Version 12.3.1

VsCode:Version: 1.67.2 (Universal) MacOS

Dotnet: 6.0.300

1. Created a new Maui App: dotnet new maui-blazor
2. dotnet publish MyMauiBlazorApp.csproj -f:net6.0-ios -c:Release /p:ServerAddress=myipaddree /p:ServerUser=myuser /p:TcpPort=58181 /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory=/Users//Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/ /p:EnableAssemblyILStripping=false /p:ServerPassword=myuserpassword
3. Did all ceremonies for publishing to App Store (app,cert,profile)
4. Published app with Transporter and Test flight
5. Download and Ran app. **All Good and app works normally**
6. Added to iOS/Info.plist

```
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>14.2</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

6. Added to MauiProgram.cs

```
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectivity>(Connectivity.Current);
```

7. Ran thru the same process as before to build .ipa and published to app store

**8. Splash Screen appears for a brief time on Iphone 12 Max Pro, then crashes. However, the same code ran successfully locally on my build macbook: dotnet build -t:Run -c:Release -f net6.0-maccatalyst  MyMauiBlazorApp.csproj**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any crash log or error message ?It helps to troubleshooting.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to collect those..kindly advice. As I said, its really just one line of code and it crashes. If you have a sample app that uses IConnectivity, I could try and let you know.

Comment: Its a MAUI Issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7945